# mysql query help insert into multiple rows with few fields same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have doubt whether this is possible.

I have two tables

1) file_master

```
file_id  |  name
-----------------
1        | readme.txt
2        | readme2.txt
3        | readme3.txt
4        | readme4.txt
5        | readme4.txt


2) user_file

user_id  |  file_id
-----------------
1        | 2
1        | 4
```

I am looking for a query like this

```
INSERT INTO user_file (user_id, file_id) VALUES (1, SELECT file_id FROM file_master WHERE file_id <= 4);
```

this should be equivalent to

```
  INSERT INTO user_file (user_id, file_id) VALUES (1, 1);
  INSERT INTO user_file (user_id, file_id) VALUES (1, 2);
  INSERT INTO user_file (user_id, file_id) VALUES (1, 3);
  INSERT INTO user_file (user_id, file_id) VALUES (1, 4);
```

In PHP I can construct multiple Insert queries using a for loop. But I am looking for a pure SQL solution... if its possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO user_file (user_id, file_id)
    SELECT 1, file_id 
    FROM file_master 
    WHERE file_id <= 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO user_file (user_id, file_id) 
  SELECT 1, file_id FROM file_master WHERE file_id <= 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re almost right:

```
INSERT INTO user_file (user_id, file_id) SELECT 1, file_id FROM file_master WHERE file_id <= 4;
```

See [`INSERT … SELECT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html).